# Identity of the "accumulating parameter" of the foldr function

Tags: haskell

the **foldr** function:

```
foldr :: (a -> b -> b) -> b -> [a] -> b
foldr func acc []      = acc
foldr func acc (x:xs)  = func x (foldr func acc xs)
```

catches patterns like those (left side)
and makes them simpler (right side)

```
sum :: [Integer] -> Integer       |  sum :: [Integer] -> Integer
sum [] = 0                        |  sum [] = 0
sum (x:xs) = x + sum xs           |  sum (x:xs) = foldr (+) 0 xs
                                  |
product :: [Integer] -> Integer   |  product :: [Integer] -> Integer
product [] = 0                    |  product [] = 0
product (x:xs) = x * product xs   |  product (x:xs) = foldr (*) 1 xs
                                  |
concat :: [[a]] -> [a]            |  concat :: [[a]] -> [a]
concat [] = []                    |  concat [] = []
concat (x:xs) = x ++ concat xs    |  concat (x:xs) = foldr (++) [] xs
----------------------------------------------------------------------
       not using folds            |           using folds
```

one thing I noticed was that the acc argument, provided as input for the fold,
seems to be exactly the neutral element / identity element of that function.

```
In Mathematics the neutral element of the addition operation + is 0
because n + 0 = n, n ∈ ℝ
```

it doesn't change anything, in other words:
With this neutral element provided as an input for the addition function, the summand equals the sum.

`(+) summand 0 = summand` or `summand + 0 = summand`

The same goes for multiplication, the product of the factor and the identiy equals the factor itelf:

`(*) factor 1 = factor`

So is this just a coincidence or is there someting bigger behind ?

Comment: Your translation table is actually wrong. You don't need the `[]` vs `(x:xs)` case distinction, only one clause `sum xs = foldr (+) 0 xs`.

Comment: (Also, you'd used `foldl'` instead of `foldr`, but that's more of a performance detail.)

Comment: It is not a coincidence. You need some "neutral" initial element to start with something. But nothing prevents you to write something like sumPlus5 = foldr 5

Comment: Also, the `mempty` element for `Product` (that is, the identity argument for multiplication) is `1`, not `0`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You're exactly right. We very often want to pass an "identity"-like element to `foldr`, so that the "starting point" doesn't affect the result at all. In fact, this is codified in Haskell with the `Monoid` typeclass. A [monoid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monoid) is an associative binary operation with an identity. The examples you provide are all examples of a monoid, and they all exist in Haskell.

- `+` on any `Num` is codified as a monoid over the [`Sum` newtype](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.11.1.0/docs/Data-Monoid.html#t:Sum).
- `*` on any `Num` is codified as a monoid over the [`Product` newtype](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.11.1.0/docs/Data-Monoid.html#t:Product).
- `++` on any list is codified as a monoid on `[a]`.

And in fact we can go one step further. Folding over a monoid is such a common practice that we can do it automatically with [`fold`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.11.1.0/docs/Data-Foldable.html#v:fold) (or [`foldMap`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.11.1.0/docs/Data-Foldable.html#v:foldMap), if you need to disambiguate). For instance,

```
import Data.Foldable
import Data.Monoid

sum :: Num a => [a] -> a
sum = getSum . foldMap Sum

product :: Num a => [a] -> a
product = getProduct . foldMap Product

concat :: [[a]] -> [a]
concat = fold
```

If you look in the source for `Foldable`, you can see that `fold` and `foldMap` are actually defined in terms of `foldr` on a monoid, so this is doing the exact same thing you just described.

You can find the full list of (built-in) `Monoid` instances on Hackage, but a few others that you might find of interest:

- `||` on Booleans is a monoid with the [`Any` newtype](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.11.1.0/docs/Data-Monoid.html#t:Any).
- `&&` on Booleans is a monoid with the [`All` newtype](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.11.1.0/docs/Data-Monoid.html#t:All).
- Function composition is a monoid with the [`Endo` newtype](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.11.1.0/docs/Data-Monoid.html#t:Endo) (short for "endomorphism")

As an exercise, you might consider trying to pinpoint the identity of each of these operations.